# Утвердительное "да" в середине фразы — пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Какой вариант пунктационного оформления предпочтительнее (с тире или без):

*"Такие ситуации — да, иногда возникают"* или *"Такие ситуации да, иногда возникают"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такие ситуации — да, иногда (они) возникают.

Здесь *такие ситуации* можно рассматривать как **именительный темы**, в этом случае ставится тире.

**Об именительном темы**

1) Википедия [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Именительный_темы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B)

Имени́тельные те́мы (именительные представления, сегмент) — **фигура речи**, на первом месте которой стоит изолированное имя существительное в именительном падеже, называющее тему последующей фразы. Его функция заключается в вызове особого интереса к предмету высказывания и усилении его звучания:

2) Ответ справочной службы русского языка  Вопрос № 286562

Эта конструкция называется сегментированной. Первый элемент в ней – **именительный темы (представления)**. После него могут стоять **точка, запятая, двоеточие, тире, вопросительный или восклицательный знак, многоточие, возможно сочетание двух знаков.** Ср.: Театр. Это слово связано с самыми ранними впечатлениями детства (Кат.); Логика мышления, ей он верил (Грос.); Студенческий быт: каким ему быть? (газ.); **Тетка – где ж она откажет, хоть какой, а все ж ты свой (Тв.)**; Любовь? Не знаю имени такого (Сельв.); Воспоминания! Как острый нож оне (Гр.); Человек будущего… О нём мечтали лучшие люди многих поколений, всех времён (Долм.); Друзья моей юности!.. Каждый из них пошел своей дорогой (Серебр.).

Comment: Спасибо! Только что за тема, не понял?

Comment: Под это больше подошло бы: _Такие ситуации — **они** иногда возникают._

Comment: @Alex_ander Мне кажется, что это разные случаи. С "они", по-моему, вторая часть лучше будет как вставка, после которой следует продолжение. Такая вставка, которую можно опустить. Не согласны? А Вы не поняли случайно, что такое *именительный темы*, Александр?

Comment: Или "это" в Вашем комментарии насчёт этого "именительного темы"? Запутался что-то...

Comment: Я это насчёт терминологии (в английском есть похожий термин - "топикализация" - сначала обозначается, потом раскрывается). Вот наше: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B

Answer (score 2):

В месте предполагаемого тире просматривается смысловой разрыв. "Такие ситуации" выглядит как повторение фрагмента из предшествующего вопроса собеседника. Возможно, вопроса не было, а говорящий его только предвосхищает (переспросив в упрощённой форме), а затем отвечает на него. Если бы вопрос реально был задан собеседником (напр. в форме "а возникают ли такие ситуации?"), то предложение делилось бы на два:

> Такие ситуации? Да, иногда возникают.

В нашем же случае, отвечая "да...", говорящий подразумевает возможный вопрос. Он мог не сразу о нём подумать (хотя это мог быть и намеренный риторический приём), начав излагать свою мысль в простой утвердительной форме; затем он останавливается и отвечает на гипотетический вопрос, не произнося его. Для *замещения* того подразумеваемого, что он пропустил, и речевой паузы в этом месте, как и для обозначения прерывания логики изложения, напрашивается тире.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр!

Comment: По-моему, такое понимание ситуации является одном из возможным. Другое: *да* служит просто для усиления (может быть заменено на *действительно*) . В Одессе сказали бы: "Такие ситуации таки да иногда возникают." Как расставлять запятые в таком случае?

Comment: Думаю, что так же: в переводе с одесского, "- **ну** да, иногда возникают".

Comment: Спасибо и Вам, и Жасмин! Разобрался теперь. :)