# Как правильно выделить вопрос внутри предложения?

Tags: запятые

> Задавшись было вопросом, откуда же идёт этот звук, я тут же получил ответ.

Нацкорпус показывает различные варианты:

1. Выделение вопроса запятыми, как в моей цитате.
2. Задавшись было вопросом: "откуда же идёт этот звук?", я тут же получил ответ.
3. Задавшись было вопросом: откуда же идёт этот звук? Я тут же получил ответ.

Какой же из этих вариантов верен? Не знаю, как называется подобная структура предложения, поэтому не знаю, как поискать и где.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107856/discussion-on-question-by-------).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. *Задавшись было вопросом, **откуда же идёт этот звук**, я тут же получил ответ.*

Первый вариант — это предложение с [**косвенным вопросом**](http://www.textologia.ru/slovari/lingvisticheskie-terminy/kosvenniy-vopros/?q=486&n=738). В нем не выражена вопросительная интонация. Оно является правильным и грамматически, и стилистически.

> **Kocвeнный вoпpoc** – этo вoпpoc, пepeдaнный в фopмe кocвeннoй peчи. Пpимep: *Oн и бeлoкypый дoктop тoнoм экзaмeнaтopoв, чyвcтвyющиx cвoю нeyмeлocть, cтaли cпpaшивaть y Aндpeя Eфимычa, кaкoй ceгoдня дeнь, cкoлькo днeй в гoдy* (Чexoв). *Oн мaлo интepecoвaлcя, ecть ли y нeгo вpaги в лaбopaтopии* (Гpaнин).

2. *Задавшись было вопросом: "откуда же идёт этот звук?", я тут же получил ответ.*

Вариант возможный, но сомнительный. Если уж оставлять знак вопроса и кавычки, то без двоеточия, как вопрос с названием. Да и не нужна здесь вопросительная интонация.

3. *Задавшись было вопросом: откуда же идёт этот звук? Я тут же получил ответ.*

Я видел подобное предложение в Нацкорпусе:

*Сначала нас коробило сопоставление священника, праздников и водки. Но задавшись вопросом: что ему делать? За деньги и в будни не пойдут.* [А. А. Фет. Из деревни. 4 (1871)]

Как там было 150 лет назад у Фета, наверное, можно выяснить. Но этот электронный вариант кажется вообще неверным.

Comment: Да-да, вот третий вариант я и видела, его пунктуацию и применила к своему. Тоже решила, что тут скидку на "возраст" надо сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Кроме косвенного вопроса, можно использовать вариант с прямой речью:

*Задавшись было вопросом: **"Откуда же идёт этот звук?"**— я тут же получил ответ.*

У Роозенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159

*На вопрос мой: **«Жив ли старый смотритель?»** — никто не мог дать мне удовлетворительного ответа* (П.).

Тире ставится после **вопросительного/восклицательного знака**, которым заканчивается прямая речь.

Выбор варианта по желанию автора. Прямая речь обладает большей **выделительной** способностью, при этом можно предать **вопросительную интонацию.**

**Пример деепричастного оборота** с частицей "было":

*Вошел в сарай, **решив было улечься на сиденье**, но, покачав головой, вышел и, постелив старую доху прямо на землю, под сосенкой, бухнулся на нее.* [Вячеслав Рыбаков. Вода и кораблики (1992)]

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что не надо ничего изобретать — ваш первый вариант вполне себе хорош.

Последний вариант вообще никуда не годится. После деепричастного оборота напрашивается завершение мысли в том же предложении, вы же обрываете его и выдаёте результат этого действия новым предложением.

И ещё: я никогда не слышал сочетаний деепричастий с "было" в том смысле, что вы хотите передать, — *только сделал что-то, как...* С глаголами — да, конечно, но не с деепричастиями или причастиями.

Comment: Помнится, вы говорили, что на счёт тире не очень хорошо разбираетесь, а теперь вон как — аж три в одном ответе) На счёт третьего варианта я с вами согласна, мне он тоже показался нелепым. Ссылку на выдачу Нацкорпуса я вам написала выше, в ответ на ваш комментарий. Даже, признаться, и не думала, что "было" тут лишнее.

Comment: Ну, какие-то понятия всё же есть в голове насчёт них. По поводу последнего я даже задавал [вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435566/%D0%A3%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/435568). ;)

Comment: О, нашла благодаря вам у себя ошибку. На счёт/насчёт)